# PDF not building in ATOM on windows using LaTeX

Tags: pdf, latex, atom-editor

I'm trying to build a pdf from a .tex file using ATOM. But the command ctrl + alt + b isn't working.

When I open the Key Binding Resolver the latextools:build has an X beside it and above it the key is mapped instead to 'editor:move-to-previous-subword-bounday'

How can I change this mapping?

I should say if I go through packages -> command palette and build it that way it works no problem.

Thanks